# merge png files to pdfbox fatal error

Tags: pdfbox

I have a fatal error
when I merged *.png files to PDF as PDFBox project

**my source code** :

private void mergePdf(File outfile, ArrayList flist)throws Exception{
        for(File f:flist){

```
        int pageCounter = 3;
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        try
        {
            for(int i=0; i<pageCounter; i++){

                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
                BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
                float width = bimg.getWidth() ;
                float height = bimg.getHeight();

                PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
                doc.addPage(page);

                PDImageXObject  pdImageXObject = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, bimg);
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObject, 10, 700);
                contentStream.close();

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            doc.save(outfile);
            doc.close();
        }
```

**this way have a fatal error.**
contentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObject, 10, 700)

like that

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:143), pid=11492, tid=2724
  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Users\DEV00\workspace\Code1Podc\hs_err_pid11492.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

please help me

Comment: Please also share C:\Users\DEV00\workspace\Code1Podc\hs_err_pid11492.log

Comment: Can you upgrade to a later JDK7? JDK7 is at build 1.7.0_80-b15.

Comment: is it necessary to compile? upgrade jdk.